# @mentions for given feeditem id through soql

Tags: apex, soql, chatter, feeditem

Is it possible to get details about @mentioned in feeditem body through soql. 
REST API and Connect API are available, but not able to locate any standard object which has this information.
Please advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, @mention information is not supported in SOQL. As you said, it's only available in the [Chatter REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_responses_ms_mention.htm) and in the methods of the [ConnectApi](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/connectapi_examples_post_feed_element_mention.htm) Apex namespace.

Comment: Do we have any limits (at user or org level) on Chatter REST API ?

Comment: Yes, see the Limits section on this documentation page: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/intro_architecture.htm

Comment: Thanks for sharing link..:) Do we have count, not able to find

Comment: We don't document the exact limits for the Chatter REST API, but they are generous enough that a client that follows best practices will not hit them. If people hit the limits, it's usually because they're using a single user to issue requests on behalf of other users. The limits are per user, per app, per hour.

Comment: I belive the limits are aligned with the limits on the general REST API.